# What is difference between MTU and fragment option in OpenVPN2.0 configuration?

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

The configuration file of OpenVPN2.0 has two parameters MTU and fragment, I know what they are used for but I cannot find out the exact difference between them. Could anyone please explain me the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to send a packet that has a length of 1500 bytes and your MTU is set to 1480 bytes, the fragmentation says whether that packet can be broken into pieces (fragments) and sent or if it should be rejected.

With a VPN you generally reduce the MTU because you need to account for the VPN overhead with each packet and fragmentation will likely increase latency.

Within OpenVPN the fragment option will set the maximum size a packet can be before it is fragmented. However this will only apply to UDP traffic, so unless you are specifically having issues with that it is best to be left alone.

According to the [OpenVPN manpage](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html) there isn't a straight MTU option though.

However there is an mssfix

> Announce to TCP sessions running over the tunnel that they should limit their send packet sizes such that after OpenVPN has encapsulated them, the resulting UDP packet size that OpenVPN sends to its peer will not exceed max bytes.
>   The max parameter is interpreted in the same way as the --link-mtu parameter, i.e. the UDP packet size after encapsulation overhead has been added in, but not including the UDP header itself.
>
> The --mssfix option only makes sense when you are using the UDP protocol for OpenVPN peer-to-peer communication, i.e. --proto udp.
>
> --mssfix and --fragment can be ideally used together, where --mssfix will try to keep TCP from needing packet fragmentation in the first place, and if big packets come through anyhow (from protocols other than TCP), --fragment will internally fragment them.
>
> Both --fragment and --mssfix are designed to work around cases where Path MTU discovery is broken on the network path between OpenVPN peers.
>
> The usual symptom of such a breakdown is an OpenVPN connection which successfully starts, but then stalls during active usage.

Comment: Does this mean fragments must always be set less than the MTU?

Answer (score 1):

Both specify the maximum size of a datagram sent over a channel. `

fragment`is implemented with openVPN 
while`MTU` restrictions are implemented by the IP layer.

Comment: So, we should define MTU always larger than or equal to fragment+OpenVPN_Header. Am I correct?

Comment: Under normal circumstances you should not need to set both. OpenVPN has lot of code for covering special corner cases on various OSes. So it might be necessary to ask with OpenVPN directly to get recommended settings for specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

MTU is the Maximum Transfer Unit. It's the largest packet size that the connection will accommodate. The second one, 'fragment', could be the TCP 'do not fragment' flag, but it's a bit vague. If that's what it is, a 'do not fragment' flag on a packet means you can't break it up, even if it's larger than the MTU, which means it gets dropped.  VPNs have to worry about this type of thing because they basically take packets that are already at MTU size, and then they add on VPN header data, which requires them to break up each packet into smaller packets to accommodate the size change.

Answer (score -2):

A maximum transmission unit (MTU) is the largest size packet or frame, specified in octets (eight-bit bytes), that can be sent in a packet- or frame-based network such as the Internet. The Internet's Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) uses the MTU to determine the maximum size of each packet in any transmission.

OpenVPN is an open source VPN daemon by James Yonan. Because OpenVPN tries to be a universal VPN tool offering a great deal of flexibility, there are a lot of options on this manual page. If you're new to OpenVPN, you might want to skip ahead to the examples section where you will see how to construct simple VPNs on the command line without even needing a configuration file.

Also note that there's more documentation and examples on the OpenVPN web site: http://openvpn.net/

And if you would like to see a shorter version of this manual, see the openvpn usage message which can be obtained by running openvpn without any parameters.

DESCRIPTION

OpenVPN is a robust and highly flexible VPN daemon. OpenVPN supports SSL/TLS security, ethernet bridging, TCP or UDP tunnel transport through proxies or NAT, support for dynamic IP addresses and DHCP, scalability to hundreds or thousands of users, and portability to most major OS platforms.

OpenVPN is tightly bound to the OpenSSL library, and derives much of its crypto capabilities from it.

OpenVPN supports conventional encryption using a pre-shared secret key (Static Key mode) or public key security (SSL/TLS mode) using client & server certificates. OpenVPN also supports non-encrypted TCP/UDP tunnels.

OpenVPN is designed to work with the TUN/TAP virtual networking interface that exists on most platforms.

Overall, OpenVPN aims to offer many of the key features of IPSec but with a relatively lightweight footprint.

OPTIONS

OpenVPN allows any option to be placed either on the command line or in a configuration file. Though all command line options are preceded by a double-leading-dash ("--"), this prefix can be removed when an option is placed in a configuration file.
--help
Show options.
--config file
Load additional config options from file where each line corresponds to one command line option, but with the leading '--' removed.
If --config file is the only option to the openvpn command, the --config can be removed, and the command can be given as openvpn file

Note that configuration files can be nested to a reasonable depth.

Double quotation characters ("") can be used to enclose single parameters containing whitespace, and "#" or ";" characters in the first column can be used to denote comments.

Note that OpenVPN 2.0 and higher performs backslash-based shell escaping, so the following mappings should be observed:

Comment: This is more a history of OpenVPN than an answer to the question.